# Нужна ли запятая перед "даже"?

Tags: пунктуация

Завтрак всё равно можно сделать особенным и вкусным **даже** без яиц и коровьего молока.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Контекст был в предыдущем предложении. "Вы придерживаетесь вегетарианства?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не ставится:

*Завтрак всё равно можно сделать особенным и вкусным // **даже без яиц и коровьего молока.***

Это простое предложение и по семантике, и по интонации. Оборот во второй части входит в основное содержание по схеме "тема – рема": о чем говорится и что говорится.

Предложение состоит из двух фраз, но пауза между ними (перед словом "даже") произносительная. Она обозначает перелом интонации и запятой не обозначается.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1. Какое **объективное правило** здесь действует? Думаю, что здесь применимо правило факультативного обособления для обстоятельственных оборотов, выраженных существительными.

Розенталь  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114

«Во многих случаях обособление или необособление обстоятельства зависит от степени распространенности оборота, его близости к основной части предложения, наличия добавочных оттенков значения, места по отношению к сказуемому, стилистической задачи и т. д., поэтому обособление  факультативно.

2. Но, может быть, всегда обособляются обороты **с частицей ДАЖЕ?** Нет, не всегда. Это слово может быть как усилительной частицей, так и использоваться в качестве присоединительного союза, например: *Это же замечательно, это показатель, что в стране можно вести бизнес даже в период кризиса.*
3. Многое зависит **от структуры предложения**? Да, безусловно, но даже при одной и той же структуре возможно разное авторское решение
4. **Контекст нужен?** Я представляю это так.

Вам нужно приготовить завтрак, но продуктов не так много, и в частности нет яиц и молока. Но не расстраивайтесь. Завтрак всё равно можно сделать особенным и вкусным (?) даже без яиц и коровьего молока.

В этом предложении возможны **два интонационных варианта:**

(1) *Завтрак всё равно можно сделать особенным и вкУсным  // **даже без яиц и коровьего молокА.***

(2)  *Завтрак всё равнО можно сделать особенным и вкусным, **даже без яиц и коровьего молокА.***

Вот и сочетание «всё равно» не задает желаемой однозначности, так как оно может выделяться или не выделяться логическим ударением.

Таким образом, вариантное решение не стоит называть «ужасом»,  даже если оно не совпадает с вашим.

Comment: Ужас! А вы логические ударения не слышите? *Завтрак всё равнО (даже при таких обстоятельствах) можно сделать особенным и вкусным, даже без яиц и коровьего молокА.* http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120 (пункт 1)

Comment: Ну спасибо, мой дорогой друг. А вы не видите, что здесь вообще нет логических ударений?  Или вы думаете, что они везде есть.  Все ударения тонические, в конце фразы. Интонация спокойная, ненапряженная. И не надо мне приводить другие предложения, так как любой текст строго индивидуален.

Comment: С ударением только в конце звучит не по-русски, так нельзя, тогда надо переформулировать. В одной части говорится, что всё равно можно сделать, а в другой уточняется, при каких именно обстоятельствах.

Comment: Все верно, но это содержание простого предложения, ничего выделять здесь не нужно. Всё это можно сказать спокойным голосом, без  интонационного выделения оборота. Это моя точка зрения, но я допускаю, что кто-то слышит и думает иначе. Дайте свой ответ. Пусть будет больше мнений, это нормально.

Comment: Но так люди не говорят, это ерунда. Очень разговорный вариант, когда человек не думал над тем, как сформулировать. Вот надо Артёма спросить, он эксперт в том, как люди говорят (постоянно на это ссылается).

Comment: Всех зовите, и Артема, конечно,  интересно послушать.  Я люблю, когда много ответов на спорные темы. Это же все-таки форум.

Comment: Нет, это не форум (так интересно утверждаете, будто это абсолютно точно так и есть), это сайт вопросов и ответов. Сколько уже можно вам говорить?

Comment: А я, как только прочитал вопрос, подумал, что здесь явно не хватает контекста и понимания авторской задумки. Поэтому вариантов может быть несколько. Пока я сконяюсь к варианту с запятой, и это из-за ***всё равно***.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Да, из-за "всё равно" требуется запятая.

Comment: Уважаемая Sharon, при всём пиетете, лично я считаю, что тут oleedd прав: вопросы требуют сперва объективного ответа, по справочникам, а уж потом вполне допустима субъективная прибавка. То есть, к примеру: "Запятая может стоять, а может не стоять, это потому-то и потому-то *(ссылки на соответствующие параграфы)*. Я считаю, что запятая тут не нужна, потому что... *(объяснение почему)*". Просто лично я не раз оказывался в ситуации, когда **субъективное мнение** мне подавали под соусом **объективного правила**, и это всякий раз создавало массу проблем.

Comment: Спасибо всем, кто принял участие в дискуссии, мне было интересно узнать ваше мнение.

Comment: *Таким образом, вариантное решение не стоит называть «ужасом», даже если оно не совпадает с вашим* — нет, так сказал, потому что без знака нельзя, раз там ударение, должен быть знак.

Comment: Это всего лишь ваше мнение,  не стоит считать его единственно правильным.

Comment: Тогда читайте без ударения на "вкусным". Это не по-русски.

Comment: @Sharon  После дополнения ответ стал не таким однозначным, как сначала (плюс).

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь! Стоило написать предыдущее предложение. "Вы придерживаетесь вегетарианства?"

Answer (score 0):

Возможен такой вариант:

***Завтрак всё равно можно сделать особенным и вкусным – даже без яиц и коровьего молока!***